# Как добавить в RecyclerView разные элемент

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

У меня есть массив карточке (CardView) которые я загружаю в RecyclerView.

Я хочу разделять эти карточка своим элементом, не пойму как это можно сделать.

К примеру:

RecyclerView 
    Заголовок1, кнопка с действием
    CardView
    CardView
    CardView
    Заголовок2, кнопка с действием
    CardView
    CardView
    CardView
    Заголовок3, кнопка с действием
    CardView
    CardView
    CardView
RecyclerView

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вам надо по позиции элемента определять его тип и в зависимости от этого загружать определённую разметку и отображать её:

```
//метод, в коем вы должны в зависимости от позиции элемента возвращать
//её тип в виде числа, кое потом используется в onCreateViewHolder для загрузки разметки
//и в onBindViewHolder для наполнения её данными
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position)
{
    if (position == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return 1;
    }
 }

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
{
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder vh;
    View itemLayoutView;

    //загружаем разметку в зависимости от типа и возвращаем
    //нужный холдер
    switch (viewType)
    {
        case 0:
            itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.zero_type_layout, parent, false);
            vh = new HolderZeroType(itemLayoutView);
            break;
        case 1:
            itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.first_type_layout, parent, false);
            vh = new HolderFirstType(itemLayoutView);
            break;
    }

    return vh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position)
{
    switch (this.getItemViewType(position))
    {
        case 0:
           HolderZeroType zero = (HolderZeroType) holder;
           //наполняем данными разметку для нулевого типа
           break;
        case 1:
           HolderFirstType first = (HolderFirstType) holder;
           //наполняем данными разметку для нулевого типа
           break;
     }
 }

public static class HolderFirstType extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    ...

    public ViewHolderText(View v)
    {
        super(v);
        ...
    }
}

public static class HolderZeroType extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    ...

    public ViewHolderText(View v)
    {
        super(v);
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Вот еще один пример в список вставляется Хедер и Футер.

Вместо энума можно использовать константы.

```
    public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

        int footerHeight;
        List<String> newCities;

        private enum ItemType {
            CARD_VIEW {
                @Override
                public int number() {
                    return 1;
                }
            },
            HEADER {
                @Override
                public int number() {
                    return 2;
                }
            },
            FOOTER {
                @Override
                public int number() {
                    return 3;
                }
            };

            public abstract int number();
        }

        private List<String> mItemList;
        private final View.OnClickListener mListener;
        private final View.OnLongClickListener mLongListener;

        public RecyclerAdapter(List<String> itemList, View.OnClickListener mListener, View.OnLongClickListener mLongListener) {
            mItemList = itemList;
            this.mListener = mListener;
            this.mLongListener = mLongListener;
            newCities = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        @Override
        public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            Context context = parent.getContext();
            if (viewType == ItemType.CARD_VIEW.number()) {
                final View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).
                        inflate(R.layout.recycler_item, parent, false);
                return new RecyclerItemViewHolder(view, mListener, mLongListener);
            } else if (viewType == ItemType.HEADER.number()) {
                final View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.recycler_header, parent, false);
                return new RecyclerEmptyViewHolder(view);
            } else if (viewType == ItemType.FOOTER.number()) {
                final View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.recycler_footer, parent, false);
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = view.getLayoutParams();
                params.height = footerHeight;
                view.requestLayout();
                return new RecyclerEmptyViewHolder(view);
            }
            throw new RuntimeException("There is no type that matches the type " + viewType + " + make sure your using types correctly");
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
            if (!(isPositionHeader(position) || isLastPosition(position))) {
                RecyclerItemViewHolder holder = (RecyclerItemViewHolder) viewHolder;
                String itemText = mItemList.get(position - 1); // we are taking header in to account so all of our items are correctly positioned
                if (newCities.contains(itemText)) {
                    holder.markCityAsNew(true);
                } else {
                    holder.markCityAsNew(false);
                }
                holder.setItemFavoriteState(PositionManager.getInstance().isFavouriteCity(itemText));
                holder.setItemText(itemText);
            }
        }

        public int getBasicItemCount() {
            return mItemList == null ? 0 : mItemList.size();
        }

        //our new getItemCount() that includes header View
        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return getBasicItemCount() + 1 + 1; // header
        }

        // returns viewType for a given position
        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            if (isPositionHeader(position)) {
                return ItemType.HEADER.number();
            }
            if (isLastPosition(position)) {
                return ItemType.FOOTER.number();
            }
            return ItemType.CARD_VIEW.number();
        }

        // check if given position is a header
        private boolean isPositionHeader(int position) {
            return position == 0;
        }

        private boolean isLastPosition(int position) {
            return position == getItemCount() - 1;
        }

        public void setFooterHeight(int height) {
            footerHeight = height * 4;
        }

        public void addCityToNewLocationsList(String city) {
            newCities.add(city);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Очень интересная библиотека, как раз может решить вашу задачу[RendererRecyclerViewAdapter](https://github.com/vivchar/RendererRecyclerViewAdapter)