# Как в RecyclerView сделать проверку на наличие определенного текста в TextView?

Tags: android, recyclerview

По замыслу хочу выводить разные Layout'ы в зависимости от того какой текст выводится в `TextView`.  У меня есть адаптер, в инете куча инфы как менять `View` в зависимости от позиции, перебрал кучу ссылок, но так и не понял, как выставить разные `View` в зависимости от того какой текст передается в `TextView`. В каком месте адаптера такую проверку нужно проводить?
Сам адаптер

```
class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.ViewHolder> 
{
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<My_data> mydata;

    DataAdapter(Context context, List<My_data> mydata)
    {
        this.mydata = mydata;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }
    @Override
    public DataAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(DataAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        My_data my_data = mydata.get(position);
        holder.nameView.setText(my_data.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount()
    {
        return mydata.size();
    }

    /*@Override public int getItemViewType(int position){}*/

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        final TextView nameView;
        ViewHolder(View view)
        {
            super(view);
            nameView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
        }
    }
}
```

Данный вопрос не является дубликатом, в других вопросах на ресурсе описывается изменение `View` с учетом позиции, а не с учетом наличия определенных данных внутри `View`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как добавить в RecyclerView разные элемент](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/510879/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2-recyclerview-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На основе [вопроса-дубликата](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/510887/177345). Ничто не мешает вам получить свой текст по позиции, сравнивать его с эталонным и возвращать идентификатор нужного типа View

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position){

    if (mydata.get(position).getName().equals("some one")) return 0;
    if (mydata.get(position).getName().equals("some two")) return 1;
 }
```

Получать данные из представления (View), как вы планируете в вопросе вообще плохая идея, их надо получать из источника (хранилища)

Comment: спасибо за помощь, эту конструкцию получения текста я все никак понять не мог.