# Почему адаптер "не видит" второй viewholder?

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Пытаюсь сделать загрузку разных макетов для пунктов списка. Изучаю, так сказать, пошагово. Смог сделать загрузку разных `layout` в пределах одного `viewholder`, но это не работает, если в разметке отсутствует `view` с заданным `id`. Для этого нужно подгружать, в зависимости от условия, разные `viewholder`. Пытаюсь реализовать с помощью [данного](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/510887/268566) ответа, но выдает такое ругательство: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Суть ошибки, в общем то, ясна, но вот как исправлять - абсолютно непонятно. Делаю, вроде, все по примеру.
Вот код адаптера, `onBindViewHolder` еще не дописал, потому что застрял на этой ошибке. Если же использовать один холдер, то `layout'ы` прекрасно меняются по условию.

```
public class MyListCursorAdapter extends CursorRecyclerViewAdapter<MyListCursorAdapter.ViewHolder>
{

public MyListCursorAdapter(Context context,Cursor cursor)
{
    super(context,cursor);
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    public TextView mTextView;
    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        mTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
    }
}

public static class ViewHolder1 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    public TextView mTextView1;
    public ViewHolder1(View view) {
        super(view);
        mTextView1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name1);
    }
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
{
    ViewHolder vh;
    View itemView;
    switch (viewType)
    {
        case 0 :
            itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
            vh = new ViewHolder(itemView);
        break;
        case 1 :
            itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_2, parent, false);
            vh = new ViewHolder1(itemView);
        break;
        default:
            itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_3, parent, false);
            vh = new ViewHolder(itemView);
        break;
    }
    return vh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, Cursor cursor)
{
    MyListItem myListItem = MyListItem.fromCursor(cursor);
    viewHolder.mTextView.setText(myListItem.getName());
}
}
```

Comment: Не называйте свои классы так же, как стандартные, чтобы не путать себя, людей и компилятор. Сделайте `ViewHolder1` и `ViewHolder2`, например.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы указали, что ваш адаптер должен работать только с классом `MyListCursorAdapter.ViewHolder`. Засим компилятор и отказывается разрешить вам другой использовать.

Расширьте перечень классов, с коими может работать адаптер, указав базовый ViewHolder - `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` - в объявлении класса, возвращаемом значении метода `onCreateViewHolder` и в аргументе метода `onBindViewHolder`

Comment: спасибо, предельно понятно