# Android RecyclerView GridView разные CardView

Tags: android, recyclerview, cardview

Я использую Firebase для приложения и мне нужно хранить разные данные(например где-то не будет хвать одной части карточки, где-то другой), скорее всего просто сделаю форму и по ней буду заполнять

НО, как сделать так, чтобы были разные адаптеры ? - Это просто смотреть на пробелы в JSON и в зависимости от содержимого ставить свой адаптер ? Тогда список не ляжет ?

Может есть какая-нибудь библиотека или спец. решение ?

Comment: Вы хотите все эти данные в один RecyclerView положить, но отображаться они у вас по разному могут?

Answer (score 0):

Смотрите здесь: [Подобный вопрос 1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/510879/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2-recyclerview-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82), [Подобный вопрос 2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/470209/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-view-%D0%B2-recyclerview)

[Статья на английском](https://medium.com/@ruut_j/a-recyclerview-with-multiple-item-types-bce7fbd1d30e)

Comment: + [статья на русском](https://habrahabr.ru/post/323862/)