# В RecyclerView отображается не весь список

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Добавил recyclerView в свою верстку, написал адаптер, все данные подгружаются и отображаются нормально, но, т.к. на странице есть другие элементы, я был вынужден отключить прокрутку в самом recyclerView, иначе он скрывался за другими элементами и прокручивался на части экрана. Чтобы прокрутка экрана выглядела целостно, весь контент был помещен в ScrollView, но, когда прокрутка в recycler была отключена, он почему-то стал отображать только 2 элемента из списка, в котором 10 элементов.

Вот функция для отображения recycler:

```
private void showFilmsList(FilmsList filmsList) {
    filmsListAdapter = new FilmsListAdapter(getContext(), filmsList.getData(), (OnClickListener) getContext(), getBaseUrl());
    filmsListView.setAdapter(filmsListAdapter);
    filmsListView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false));
    filmsListView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
}
```

Вот код адаптера:

```
package x.x.x.ui.main;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.core.text.HtmlCompat;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.List;

import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import by.seobility.kinoclub.R;
import by.seobility.kinoclub.repo.models.Film;
import by.seobility.kinoclub.utils.OnClickListener;

public class FilmsListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FilmsListAdapter.FilmsListViewHolder> {

private List<Film> films;
private String baseUrl;
private Context context;
OnClickListener onClickListener;

public FilmsListAdapter(Context context, List<Film> films, OnClickListener onClickListener, String baseUrl) {
    this.films = films;
    this.context = context;
    this.onClickListener = onClickListener;
    this.baseUrl = baseUrl;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public FilmsListViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_films_list, parent, false);
    return new FilmsListAdapter.FilmsListViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull FilmsListAdapter.FilmsListViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.bindData(films.get(position));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return films != null ? films.size() : 0;
}

public class FilmsListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    @BindView(R.id.films_list_title)
    TextView title;
    @BindView(R.id.films_list_poster)
    ImageView poster;
    @BindView(R.id.films_list_rate_text)
    TextView rateText;
    @BindView(R.id.films_list_category)
    TextView category;
    @BindView(R.id.films_list_year)
    TextView year;
    @BindView(R.id.films_list_qualities)
    TextView qualities;
    @BindView(R.id.films_list_translations)
    TextView translations;

    public FilmsListViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
    }

    public void bindData(Film film) {
        itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if (onClickListener != null){
                onClickListener.onFilmClick(film);
            }
        });

        title.setText(film.getTitle());
        String posterUrl = baseUrl + film.getPoster();
        Picasso.get().load(posterUrl).into(poster);
        rateText.setText(film.getRating());
        category.setText(HtmlCompat.fromHtml(context.getResources().getString(R.string.category,
                "<font color='#FFFFFF'>" + film.getCat() + "</font>"),
                HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));
        year.setText(HtmlCompat.fromHtml(context.getResources().getString(R.string.year,
                "<font color='#FFFFFF'>" + film.getYear() + "</font>"),
                HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));
        String qualitiesString = listToString(film.getQualites());
        qualities.setText(HtmlCompat.fromHtml(context.getResources().getString(R.string.qualites,
                "<font color='#FFFFFF'>" + qualitiesString + "</font>"),
                HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));
        String translationsString = listToString(film.getTranslations());
        translations.setText(HtmlCompat.fromHtml(context.getResources().getString(R.string.translations,
                "<font color='#FFFFFF'>" + translationsString + "</font>"),
                HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));
    }
}

private String listToString(List<String> list){
    if (list.isEmpty()) return "false";
    StringBuilder return_string = new StringBuilder();
    for (String s : list){
        return_string.append(s).append(", ");
    }
    return return_string.toString().substring(0, return_string.length() - 2);
}
}
```

Разметка:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/dark_grey"
tools:context=".ui.main.MainFragment">

<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/dp60"
    android:background="@color/black"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_bold"
        android:text="@string/toolbar_text"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="@color/orange"
        android:textSize="@dimen/toolbar_text_size" />

</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/rootView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/top_slider"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/dp20"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_gray_background"
            android:padding="@dimen/dp15"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/rootView"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/rootView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/rootView" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/series_update"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dp50"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/dp20"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_gray_background"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/rootView"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/rootView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/top_slider">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/series_update_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_bold"
                android:paddingStart="@dimen/dp15"
                android:text="@string/series_update"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/series_update_icon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingEnd="@dimen/dp15"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:tint="@color/white" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <net.cachapa.expandablelayout.ExpandableLayout
            android:id="@+id/series_update_expandable"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:el_duration="1000"
            app:el_expanded="false"
            app:el_parallax="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/rootView"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/rootView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/series_update">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/series_update_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/dp20" />

        </net.cachapa.expandablelayout.ExpandableLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/filter_frame_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/dp20"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_orange_border"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/orderText"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/rootView"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/rootView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/series_update_expandable">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/filter_layout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:padding="@dimen/dp15">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/filter_icon"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/filter"
                    app:tint="@color/orange" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/filter_text"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_bold"
                    android:text="@string/filter"
                    android:textColor="@color/orange"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </FrameLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/orderText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dp20"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dp20"
            android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_bold"
            android:text="@string/sorted_by"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/order_by_spinner"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/rootView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/filter_frame_layout" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/order_by_spinner"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dp20"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp10"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dp20"
            android:background="@drawable/spinner_style"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/order"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/rootView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/orderText" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/order"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/rootView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/order_by_spinner"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/order_by_spinner">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/order_desc"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dp20"
                android:src="@drawable/sort_desc"
                android:padding="@dimen/dp10"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_orange_border"
                app:tint="@color/orange" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/order_asc"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dp20"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:src="@drawable/sort_asc"
                android:padding="@dimen/dp10"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_orange_border"
                app:tint="@color/orange" />

        </FrameLayout>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/films_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dp20"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/rootView"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/rootView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/order_by_spinner"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/rootView"/>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</ScrollView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Проблема в recycler с id films_list.

Comment: думаю, тут нужно на вёрстку смотреть

Comment: Таки да, скорее всего в разметке беда. С другой стороны - помещать RecyclewView в ScrollView - обычно плохая идея, т.к. нафига тогда вообще RecyclewView. Обычно правильнее - всё что вокруг RecyclewView надо в RecyclewView же и поместить, через механизм отображения разных типов ячеек.

Comment: Добавил разметку.

Comment: Попробуйте у ConstraintLayout внутри ScrollView поставить высоту wrap_content, а то она у вас сейчас 0, что представляется неправильным.

Comment: Пробовал, не помогло.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Уберите ScrollView, он не используется вместе с recyclerView.
2. Используйте разные типы и подгружайте их в список.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Не подскажете статью хорошую по различным типам данных в recyclerview?

Comment: @Feelini попробуйте посмотреть вот эту тему https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/510879/Как-добавить-в-recyclerview-разные-элемент/510887#510887

Comment: Спасибо, буду разбираться.

Comment: Если кому-то будет полезно, вот еще нашел такую статью: https://ziginsider.github.io/Multiple_Row_Types_In_Recyclerview/
Хотя ссылка может потерять свою актуальность.

Comment: Сегодня решил эту проблему. Вместо ScrollView необходимо использовать NestedScrollView, а в recyclerView установить флажок android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"